# Why is document.getElementById() not working?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to make a program which adds a textbox every time you click a button. Here's my code:

```js
window.onload = function () { linelist = document.getElementById("linelist"); };
function AddLine() {
    linelist.innerHTML += "<div class=\"normallink\"><input type=\"text\"><button class=\"dustbin\"><img src=\"dustbin.png\"></button></div><br />";
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>

<body>
  <div id="linelist"></div><br />
  <button id="addline" onclick="Addline();">+</button>
</body>

</html>
```

When I run it, it generates an error. Why is this occurring?

Comment: Your function name is `AddLine` but you used `Addline` onclick handler

Comment: Voting to close because the problem is caused by a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to define `linelist` outside the functions first with `let` or `var`:

```
let linelist = null;
window.onload = function () { linelist = document.getElementById("linelist"); };
function AddLine() {
    linelist.innerHTML += "<div class=\"normallink\"><input type=\"text\"><button 
class=\"dustbin\"><img src=\"dustbin.png\"></button></div><br />";
}
```

Comment: That's true only in strict mode, which this code isn't using. Here it creates an implicit global which is bad practice, but perfectly function and not the cause of the problem,